# Wrap element pairs in a div javaScript / jQuery (complex)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a solution to wrap elements in pair of two elements where outer can have elements in any form that is, elements can be in even or odd number. Please suggest a solution that is more like a plugin sort of solution.

Current Structure

```
<div class="outer-wrap-1">
    <h1>Some Heading</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="outer-wrap-2">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="outer-wrap-3">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I wan some jQuery Solution to obtain result as

```
<div class="outer-wrap-1">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Some Heading</h1>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer-wrap-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer-wrap-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: I tried a lot of stuff and js librared to obtain desired result but couldn't get it.
I know it my fault that I haven't posted the  solutions I tried. Will keep it mind from the next time

Answer (score -1):

Use children(),  slice() and wrapAll()

```js
// add some text to empty items for demo
$('.item').text(function(i) {return 'Item ' + (i + 1)});

// wrapping plugin
$.fn.wrapChildren = function(opts) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var $children = $(this).children();
    for (var i = 0; i < $children.length; i = i + opts.numItems) {
      $children.slice(i, i + opts.numItems)
               .wrapAll('<div class="' + opts.className + '">');
    }
  });
}


$('.outer-wrap-1, .outer-wrap-2, .outer-wrap-3')
     .wrapChildren({className: 'row', numItems:2});
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer-wrap-1">
  <h1>Some Heading</h1>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="outer-wrap-2">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="outer-wrap-3">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```